# How does the Blasting Wilder archetype work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

The [Blasting Wilder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/blasting-wilder)'s modified Wild Surge ability says (emphasis mine):

> A blasting wilder uses her wild surge not to improve her psionic
>   powers, but to enhance her surge blast ability. Any time the blasting
>   wilder invokes a wild surge, she gains no increase to her manifester
>   level, but adds one die of damage to her surge blast for each point of
>   the wild surge and can expend her psionic focus to use her surge blast
>   as a free action in the same round she used her wild surge, although
>   she may only do this once per round, even if wild surging more than
>   once per round. This ability functions in all other ways as Wild
>   Surge, *including the risk of psychic enervation*, and is modified by
>   the wilder’s surge choice as normal. Wild surges that do not increase
>   the manifester level, such as Efficient Surge, cannot be used with
>   this archetype.

I am confused how this would work out in practice. For starters, the [Surge Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/#TOC-Surge-Blast-Su-) description says that Surge Blasts do not trigger Psychic Enervation at all; however, it is unclear whether firing a Surge Blast counts as using a Wild Surge. On top of that, the regular Wilder class text implies, but does not outright state, that a Wild Surge can only be invoked to manifest a Power -- yet the Blasting Wilder text would seem to contradict this.

To be more specific, which (if any) of the following sequences of actions are legal on a Blasting Wilder's turn ?

- **Standard:** Invoke Wild Surge to manifest a Power. **Free:** expend Psionic Focus to fire a Surge Blast.
- **Standard:** Surge Blast. **Free:** expend Psionic Focus to fire an additional Surge Blast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [Surge Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/wilder/#TOC-Surge-Blast-Su-) twice in a round because you would need a way to regain your [Psionic Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/#TOC-Psionic-Focus) before blasting again.

> A wilder can channel her wild surge into a blast of uncontrolled phrenic energy. **As a standard action and by expending psionic focus**, the wilder can make a ranged touch attack (range 30’) that deals 1d6 points of force damage for every +1 to her wild surge.

Other than that, you may use your *Wild Surge* to "enhance" (in quotes because its not modified at all) a power and then use your *Wild Blast* as a free action (modified by the archetype) and still expending your *Psionic Focus* (as normal), but now causing additional damage (also modified by the archetype).

The archetype also doesn't modify or alter your *Wild Blast* ability, meaning that you may still use it as a standard action (and expending your focus) to blast an enemy without manifesting a power or using your *Wild Surge* ability.

If you are able to regain your *Psionic Focus* as a move action (see [Psychic Meditation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/psionic-meditation-psionic/)), then you should be able to start your turn focused and do the following:

- **Standard**: Manifest a power also activating your *Wild Surge*;
- **Free**: *Wild Blast* expending your focus;
- **Move**: Regain your focus again and repeat this sequence in the next turn.

If you manifest a power that is quicker than a standard action (like a [Inevitable Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/i/inevitable-strike)), then you may be able to *Surge Blast* twice in a turn, but you won't be focused at the start of the next round:

- **Standard**: *Wild Blast* expending your focus;
- **Move**: Regain your focus;
- **Swift** Manifest [Inevitable Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/i/inevitable-strike) also activating your *Wild Surge*;
- **Free**: *Wild Blast* again expending your focus.

Finally, note that you may still manifest a power without paying its cost by using your *Wild Surge* ability, instead of using the ability to cast a *Surge Blast*.

Comment: Yes, I have also noticed the synergy with Inevitable Strike. Thanks, your explanation does make sense to me.

Comment: I was trying to pick a power that is a swift action and is available at early levels. But it combines with a couple of other higher level powers too.